# How to add the text input value to the end of the URL in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am new to HTML; I need to append the number in the text input to the end of the url. How can I do that?

```
<input type=\"number\" id=\"b\" name=\"b\" value=\"1\">\
<script>
  var str,i;
  i= parseInt(b.value);
  str+="<a href=/t"+i+">Send</a>";
</script>
```

When I tried with the above sample code, when  click send it always sends the initial value of `b` that is "1". Even though I changed the value of `b` and tried to send it, it is sending the same initial value.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why are you trying to escape the quotes with `\` characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can search element using id

```
var el = document.getElementById("b")
```

access its value using `.value`

```
var val =el.value
```

And set it to url using `window.location`

```
var url = window.location.href; // this will return current url
url += "?key=" + val;
window.location.href=url;
```

Also reason why you are not getting updated value is because you are calling your script on page load. You will have to update it on an event. Look for `blur` event, or you can have a button and on click event, compute url and route to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="1">
<a id="c" href="">Send</a>

<script>
  document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var i = document.getElementById("b").value;
    this.setAttribute("href", "/t" + i);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it writes the initial value of the 'number' box at page load time.  A quick version of what you want is:

```
<input type="number" id="b" name="b" value="1" onchange="link1.href='t/'+parseInt(b.value);">
<a id="link1" href="">Send</a>
```

This code works in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.  You might want to use jQuery or document.getElementById to do the page element referencing.